# Convergence of $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{{1}-\sqrt{{1}-\sqrt{{1-\sqrt{{1}}}...}}}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, solution-verification, radicals, fake-proofs, nested-radicals

Recently, as is evident from many of my recent questions, I have been very interested in nested radicals. Recently I attempted to investigate the following infinite nested radical and arrived at a strange, counter-intuitive result.
$$\sqrt{1-\sqrt{{1}-\sqrt{{1}-\sqrt{{1-\sqrt{{1...}}}}}}}$$
At first glance, it would seem that the value of the nested radical must be either $0$ or $1$. However, if we make the assumption that a single value can be assigned to it, ie it converges, we arrive at a different value for it:
Let
$$x=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{{1}-\sqrt{{1}-\sqrt{{1-\sqrt{{1...}}}}}}}\implies x=\sqrt{1-x}\implies x^2=1-x \implies x^2+x-1=0$$
Using the quadratic formula, we get $$x=\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}$$
as $x$ is necessarily positive. Can this result be true? Or is my assumption that allowed me to label the radical as $x$ and assume it converges incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it can be true, but you have to show that there is this convergence. Define an appropriate sequence and prove that it is Cauchy. This way, assigning a value $x$ to the limit point would be justified

Comment: If you put $x_1=0$ then $x_2=\sqrt {1-x_1}=1$ and $x_3=\sqrt {1-x_2}=0$ so there is no convergence. If you set $x_1=a$ with $0\lt a\lt 1$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt {1-x_n}$ you could investigate what happens then ... It is interesting also to ponder what meaning such a nested radical has, and how it is given meaning - of what is it the limit, for example.

Comment: Assuming it converges, the value you get is absolutely correct. That value is the only one possible converged point. However, without that converging assumption, yeah, 0,1 iterating values is also possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever we find $\ldots$ in a formula we must be clear what they are meaning. My interpreation of a formula like
$$\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\ldots}}}}$$
is that this is the limit of the sequence
$$x_1=\sqrt{1}\\
x_2=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1}}\\
x_3=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1}}}\\
\ldots\\
x_{n+1}=\sqrt{1-x_n}$$

If this is the meaning of this expression then we have

$$x_1=1\\
x_2=0\\
x_3=1\\
x_4=0\\
x_5=1\\
x_6=0\\
\ldots
$$

and this sequence does not converge at all.

---

Your calculation says:

> If $x_n$ converges, then the limit will be $\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}$ or $\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}$

This is true. But $x_n$ does not converge, so this result is useless.

Comment: Oh, yes. in this interpretation, with x_1 is sqrt(1), yes, the sequence does not converge.

Comment: @JoeyCho is there another interpretation?

Comment: Yes, if it starts from 0<a<1 value as @Mark Bennet explained. x_1=1 is sortof initialization. I think this initialization could be setup as 0<a<1 value. Then it converges.

Comment: @JoeyCho So you really think the formula $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{{1}-\sqrt{{1}-\sqrt{{1-\sqrt{{1...}}}}}}}$ can stand for the limit of $\sqrt{0.17}, \sqrt{1-\sqrt{0.17}}, \sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{0.17}}},\ldots$ and not only for the limit of $\sqrt{1}, \sqrt{1-\sqrt{1}}, \sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1}}},\ldots$? I don't understand this.